# Sumo, TraCI: How to set the simulation time?

Tags: python, sumo

In the TraCi doc I found the method for retrieving the current simulation time via `connection.simulation.getTime()` but no method to set it. I specifically want to reset it to zero.

Is that possible and how do I do it?

[This](https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._simulation.html#SimulationDomain-getTime) is the link to the page in the doc where I found `getTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible but you can reload your simulation using simulation.load, which will restart.